# Sort List map by it's values keeping the order in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a game that takes the score and the name of a player after that I want to sort the scores by the highest value keeping it with the name of player that scored it. I have two options and don't know which is best and how to do it. The first is like:

```
List<Map> myList = [
  { 'name' : 'John', 'score': 23},
  { 'name' : 'Frederick', 'score': 61},
  { 'name' : 'Morgana', 'score': 48},
  { 'name' : 'Spoke', 'score': 36},
];
```

And the second is:

```
var info = {
  "name": ['John', 'Frederick', 'Morgana', 'Spoke'],
  "score": [23, 61, 48, 36],

};
```

The expected output is:

```
Frederick: 61
Morgana: 48
Spoke: 36
John: 23
```

Comment: Id highly recommend making a `Player` object that has the value `name`,  `score` and probably give it a unique `id`. Then to sort use dart's `sort()` method
`List<Player> players = ["all your players"]`
`players.sort(a, b) => a.score.compareTo(b.score));`

Answer (score 1):

First is the best solution for your case. Because it has an association between name and score. You cant sort it like this:

```
myList.sort((person1, person2) => person2['score'] - person1['score'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to implement [Comparable](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/Comparable-class.html) on your class.

```dart
class Player implements Comparable<Player> {
  final String name;
  final int score;

  const Player(this.name, this.score);

  @override
  int compareTo(Player other) {
    return other.score - score;
  }
}

void main() {
  List<Player> players = [
    Player('John', 23),
    Player('Frederick', 61),
    Player('Morgana', 48),
    Player('Spoke', 36),
  ];
  players.sort();
  print(players.map((player)=> player.score)); // (61, 48, 36, 23)
}
```